# Is it a bug that generators don't work when passed to "numpy.array"?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, generator

If a generator is passed to `numpy.array`, `numpy` does not iterate over the object, nor does it complain, **even if `copy=True`**. Any attempt to index into the array fails, frequently much later and in far away code.

I understand that numpy wants to know the size of the array from the beginning, but this behavior is not good. It should either copy to an intermediate list or raise an exception.

Comment: This is the normal behavior when passing a single, non-sequence type object to the `np.array` constructor.  E.g. `np.array({1:2}`, `np.array(set())`, `np.array(2)` In other words, `np.array` checks if your object is a *sequence*, if it is not a sequence (and does not define `__array__`)  it assumes you want an array with a single object (the one you are passing).

Comment: Some argue that `np.array` should raise an error if it's not an iterable, and you don't explicitly specify `dtype=object`.  For now it's your responsibility to give `np.array` an appropriate input, and to verify the return shape and dtype.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug, but normal behaviour. If you want to create a array from an iterator, use `fromiter`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = (i*i for i in range(7))
>>> numpy.array(a)
array(<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10dbc1b40>, dtype=object)
>>> numpy.fromiter(a, dtype=float)
array([  0.,   1.,   4.,   9.,  16.,  25.,  36.])
```

Comment: Yep. Note, it's the exact same behavior as passing any single, non-sequence object, e.g. `{}` or `set()`

Answer (score 1):

No it's a design decision. If you want to pass in a generator you need to use [`np.fromiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html):

```
>>> np.fromiter((i for i in range(10)), float)
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
```

or convert it to a `list` before calling `np.array`:

```
>>> np.array(list(your_iterator))
```

---

One reason for this is that numpy needs to iterate over the object several times: once to determine the length/dytpe of the resulting array and once to insert the items. That doesn't play well with generators and iterators which can be iterated only once. Also Generators can be infinite in length (i.e. `itertools.count`) and/or use "too much memory".

The rationale probably was: If someone wants to use generators to create an array it's going to use a lot of memory and will be slow - so it should be done intentionally: either by casting it to a list or using `np.fromiter`.

Comment: But why not raise an exception? The resulting object is useless in any case.

Comment: @Eduardo Because that's not in the spirit of duck-typing (it would require an explicit check for generators/iterators because `object`-arrays are "generally useful"!) and less performant (that check takes time, especially if you have a nested structure and need to test each item). However, you can simply ask them if they could implement it (their [bug tracker](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues) is public).